# what is the best way to store alerts where many users may subscribe to an alert?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, alert

I have a system which responds to different types of events:

Type1 events
Type2 events
Type3 events
...

The purpose of the system is to give users alerts for the types they subscribe to.

I also have users who can subscribe to each of these events.
Relational database seem unwieldly for storing which types of events a user is subscribed to. How I set to implement in SQL Server is as the following user's table:

```
userId   |    Type1    |   Type2   |   Type 3
----------------------------------------------
1        |    True     |           |          
2        |             |   True    |   True
```

This might seem already for where we only have two or three types of events, but not when we have hundreds, which is my case.

Can I still implement this in relational databases - and what would I need to change?

Comment: If it's only `true` or `false` you can also think about `subscribed` and `not subscribed`. I would not create one columns per type, but use only one column `type` and then store, if the user is subscribed. In your example you would have 3 rows (1, 1), (2,2) and (2,3) where the first column represents the `userId` and the second column the `typeId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can still implement this, using relational database.

Let's assume a table `users`

| userId | firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lloyd | Earsley |
| 2 | Rose | Xavier |

and you have a second table, where you want to store event subscriptions, called `user_event_subscriptions`:

| userId | event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

To now check, which users are subscribed for `event1`, you can `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  users AS u 
INNER JOIN 
  user_event_subscriptions AS ues 
ON 
  u.userId = ues.userId 
WHERE 
  ues.event = 1
```

To check, for which events a user is subscribed, (for example Lloyd Earsley), you can query:

```sql
SELECT 
  event 
FROM 
  user_event_subscriptions AS ues 
INNER JOIN 
  user AS u 
ON 
  ues.userId = u.userId 
WHERE 
  u.userId = 1
```